# Find a directory and launch an executable in it

Tags: bash, find, exec

I've to find a directory named 'A' and then launch an executable named 'B' that's in it that takes a path as argument and have a line with an execl() :

```
    execl("./C","C",path,(char*)0);
    perror("Exec failed");
```

where C is in 'A' and has suid bit set.

. 
I've thought of something like:

```
    find -name A -execdir {}/B path \
```

However what I get is:

```
    Exec failed: Permission denied
```

What's wrong ? Launching B from A give me no errors.

Sorry if it is a stupid question, I'm really new to bash script. Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run B through that `find` command, the current directory is the directory containing A (i.e. the parent directory of A), not A.

You'll get the right directory if you run `find -path '*/A/B' -execdir {} \;`.

This may or may not be the right way to solve your real-world problem. In this example, `B` serves no purpose, so it's hard to guess what the real-world problem is. Did you consider `sudo`?